# Sync FaceBook Birthdays with iOS Calendar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to add birthdays to facebook using my Calendar application, i.e Sync facebook *my calender* with my calender application events.

Meaning: if I create a birthday in my calender application it has to add in facebook *birthdays* (facebook my calender).

Please guide me with this issue, if any tutorials or sample code will help more, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Try see at this links

[Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

and

[getInfo values](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/users.getInfo/)

Hope this was a helpful

Comment: Thanks for reply,but i want to add one birthday into facebook my calender using my app please send me sample code. thanks again

Comment: A sample code will be a source code of your app =) This is needing a many time and testing for crash